# Timeout with SimpleTimeLimiter - shutting down application take much time

Tags: java, timeout, guava

I am using Guava's SimpleTimeLimiter to get Timeout functionality. The problem is that shutting down the app (if it's finished) take 30s as soon as i use the SimpleTimeLimiter (this time does not change if i change timeout). If i call `new MyCallable().call()` directly all works fine - app is shut down as soon as last task is finished.

The app itself has an own shutdown hook to be able to handle ctrl-c (to finish last task). The app uses a H2- embedded db and Network.

I tried to profile with visualvm - the time at the end is not recorded?! This long waiting period tooks placed before my shutdown hook is called (probably another shutdown hook?).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: The profiler shows nothing as it's concerned with running threads and there's just some 30s idling. I don't think it comes from the `SimpleTimeLimiter` itself, I'd check the thread pool used or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create `SimpleTimeLimiter` with default constructor - he create own `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` that you can't control, So your application what until all threads will be completed. from Javadoc

> ... Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are
>       terminated and removed from the cache....

If you create own ExecutorService and create SimpleTimeLimiter with this executorService then you can shutdown executorService on your shutdown hook.

```
private final ExecutorService executor;
private final TimeLimiter timeLimiter;

...
executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
timeLimiter = new SimpleTimeLimiter(executor);
...

public void shutdown() {
  if (executor == null || executor.isShutdown()) {
    return;
  }
  executor.shutdown();
  try {
    executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    log.log(Level.WARNING, "Interrupted during executor termination.", e);
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
  executor.shutdownNow();
}
```